# Enabling or Disabling Indexes for Foreign Keys with Hibernate

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have a simple database schema with two tables A and B that have been modeled as entities using Hibernate. Each row from B has a foreign key that uniquely identifies a row of A.

I have noticed that if I use Postgres as database, by default no index is created for foreign keys. Since I have lot of rows and some delete cascade configured, I decided to configure my Hibernate entity to use the JPA @Index annotation. It works well and I can see that the index is created.

However, for some reasons I had to switch to another database backend: HSQLDB. The JPA annotation for creating my index is taken into account but since HSQLDB creates by default an index for all foreign keys, I eventually have 2 indexes for the same column.

I have read that the creation of indexes for foreign keys is database provider specific (e.g. Oracle and Postgres do not create indexes but MySQL and HSQLDB do).

I am wondering if there is a way to enable/disable the creation of indexes for foreign keys whatever the provider is? otherwise it looks like I have to cope with double indexing.

Any idea, comment, suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am in a similar situation, our product has to support a variety of rdbms (firebird,mssql,oracle,db2). we just create indices for all the foreign keys on all rdbms's. 
for larger projects it is also a good idea to not rely on hibernates hbm2ddl feature for database setup. solutions like flyway or liquibase offer more control over your ddl (albeit at the price of additional code you have to write and maintain).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this in HSQLDB... unless you want to download the source code and tweak it yourself.

From [HSQLDB docs](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/guide.html#N10255):

> HSQLDB creates indexes internally to support PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY constraints: a unique index is created for each PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint; an ordinary index is created for each FOREIGN KEY constraint. Because of this, you should not create duplicate user-defined indexes on the same column sets covered by these constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's my issue. I wonder if there is a way to configure it at the Hibernate level, at least to avoid two indexes for the same column. Unfortunately, based on _lumue_ answer, it looks like it is not possible.